# Form Data is Sending but it got manipulated on controller Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update the Ticket(`SET Deleted = TRUE` because I also have to show deleted Tickets). For that I am using `POST` method on form with the Ticket ID on it but when form submits that Ticket ID changed to the latest Ticket ID.

When I inspect I see the exact Ticket ID in the action but when submitting, it get change.

I also tried to pass it a hidden input but unfortunately it get change to latest Ticket as well.

Blade

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($Tickets as $Ticket)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
        <td>{{$Ticket->Customer->Name}}</td>
        <td>$ {{$Ticket->Paid}}</td>
        <td>$ {{$Ticket->TDisc}}</td>
        <td>{{$Ticket->Tax}}</td>
        <td>{{ date("d M Y", strtotime($Ticket->Date))}}</td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <a href="/Ticket/{{$Ticket->ID}}">EDIT</a>
            <a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('Delete').submit();">DELETE</a>
            <form id="Delete" action="Ticket/{{$Ticket->ID}}" method="POST" style="display: one;">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="{{{{$Ticket->ID}}}}"
                @csrf
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Controller

```php
public function destroy(Request $request, $id) {
    dd($id);
    Ticket::where('ID', $id)->update(['Deleted' => TRUE]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Ticket has been Deleted');
}
```

Kindly help me figure out what I'm missing.

Any help would be much valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that your code will always target the first instance, as the `id` of each form is the exact same.

You shouldn't set the same `id` for any element more than once.

A better way to do it would be something like below, which will submit the correct form (the one containing the `<a>` tag).
You are also missing the method field to tell laravel it's a delete request.

```
<form action="Ticket/{{$Ticket->ID}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="{{$Ticket->ID}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <a href="" onclick="event.preventDefault(); this.parentNode.submit();">
        DELETE
    </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! You are really awesome.